# 【RN v0.57.4】undefined is not an object(evaluating 'warnings.filter')

Tags: react-native

### Description

Executing `npm i` and `react-native run-android` in an existing rn project(`iOS`normally), ran successfully but error produced with red screen:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'warnings.filter')
```

### React Native version:

```
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.5
      CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8100B CPU @ 3.60GHz
      Memory: 43.46 MB / 8.00 GB
      Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.10.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.17.3 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 23, 26, 27, 28
        Build Tools: 23.0.1, 26.0.1, 27.0.3, 28.0.2, 28.0.3
        System Images: android-23 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-23 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-23 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-27 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
      Xcode: 11.3.1/11C505 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: ^16.6.0-alpha.8af6728 => 16.13.1
      react-native: 0.57.4 => 0.57.4
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native-demo-for-npm: 1.0.16
      react-native-update-cli: 0.1.0
```

### Steps To Reproduce

1. Execute `npm i` in an existing project
2. run `react-native run-android`

### Expected Results

Run Android successfully without any errors.

I have alredy searched many solutions for this issue, but unfortunately, no any solutions finally. Any help for this is appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: a stack trace of the error can help understand the cause of the error, can you edit your question to provide that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should find the `warnings` variable in your codebase. If it is exists then maybe the error occured from that part. It could be an undefined so you should change code like

```
warnings && warnings.filter...
```

or

```
if(warnings) {
  warnings.filter..
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know what you mean. But I don’t think that’s reasonable. Because if I do it following your steps. It won’t print warnings any more on android. The file path of this error is ` node_modules/react-native/Libraries/YellowBox/Data/YellowBoxRegistry.js` for the method-`handleUpdated`. What I expect is print warnings on both iOS and Android.